# How can I compare the results of two queries?

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I'd like to compare two query results to see if they are the same or not. If the result is the same, I want to display a `MessageBox`; if not do something else.

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(query1, conn1))
{
    string result1 = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}

using (OracleCommand ctCommand = new OracleCommand("query2", conn1))
{
    string result2 = ctCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}

if (result1 == result2)
    MessageBox.Show("They are same");
else
    MessageBox.Show("They are not same");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the variables outside the `using` statements so they're visible outside that scope.

Comment: If I declare variable outside the using statements they would be visible but my ctCommand and crtCommand wont be visible...

Answer (score 0):

If both your queries return string output you can use string.Compare method to compare them and conditionally do what you want to do, base on output. However, it can't be that simple what you are asking. Can you elaborate further your question?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is declare the strings outside of the using blocks but still assign them inside the using blocks.

```
string result1;
string result2;

using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(query1, conn1))
{
    result1 = crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}

using (OracleCommand ctCommand = new OracleCommand("query2", conn1))
{
    result2 = ctCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}

if (result1.Equals(result2))
    MessageBox.Show("They are same");
else
    MessageBox.Show("They are not same");
```

Also I recommend replacing your `==` with [`.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx), if you want you can set options to make it case insensitive too so `THIS` and `this` are considered equal

```
if (result1.Equals(result2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    MessageBox.Show("They are same");
else
    MessageBox.Show("They are not same");
```